# Create context menu on browserAction onclick

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

Its been hours now that I've been stuck in this problem, does anyone know how to show a context menu every time the user clicks on the google chrome extension. 
I managed to display the menu with my default_popup, but I found out that I should implement this on a context menu.

Here's the image:
[image]

I have this following code

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Hello Toolbar",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "A Toolbar that helps.",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "cookies",
        "http://*/*",
        "tabs",
        "contextMenus"
    ]
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener( function(tab){
    chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "Test parent item", "contexts": ['page']}); 
});
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Where do you expect the context menu (entry) to appear?

Comment: @RobW A bit lower on my chrome extension. It's like a pop up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that your expectation of the [`chrome.contextMenus`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html) API is wrong. It can *never* be used to *open* a context menu. It can only tell Chrome to show context menu entries when some custom conditions have been met (see the documentation of the [`create` method](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html#method-create) for to learn about defining these conditions).

In the screencast below, I show the expected behaviour for your code.

[image]

- No context menu shows up unless the user right-clicks.
- After clicking the browser action button, the context menu entry shows up when opening the context menu within the page.

If you want a "popup" to appear on click, use the `"default_popup"` entry in the `"browser_action"` section of the manifest file. Then, the following shows up:

[image]

You can use CSS to get the popup to look like a "context menu". The [Browser action documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html) provides an [some examples](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/browserAction/).

Comment: ah. yes thanks for this valuable information. Now I can proceed and continue with my "default_popup".